# Protractor v5.3.0 & Protractor-Cucumber-Framework v4.2.0 not working with IE11 on Windows 10

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor, cucumber, internet-explorer-11

**Summary:**

I am using Protractor v5.3.0 & Protractor-Cucumber-Framework v4.2.0 on Windows 10. I've put together a sample test project in Javascript using the WebStorm IDE. I have no trouble runnnig the sample test scenario using the Chrome browser. Yet when I try to use IE11 the same test scenario fails to run. Instead I see the following error message displayed on the WebStorm terminal window:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.15063]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\<user name>\<project name>\WebStorm\protractorCucumberTest_v2>node_modules\.bin\protractor cucumber.config.js
(node:17976) [DEP0022] DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() instead.
[15:58:12] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[15:58:12] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
F---

Failures:

1) Scenario: Protractor and Cucumber Test # features\testone.feature:7
   × Given I go to "https://angularjs.org/" # features\step_definitions\testone.steps.js:73
       JavascriptError: Error executing JavaScript
       Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:33:15.31Z'
       System info: host: <computer name>, ip: <ip address>, os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '9.0.4'
       Driver info: driver.version: unknown
           at Object.checkLegacyResponse (C:\Users\<user name>\<project name>\WebStorm\protractorCucumberTest_v2\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:546:15)
           at parseHttpResponse (C:\Users\<user name>\<project name>\WebStorm\protractorCucumberTest_v2\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:509:13)
           at doSend.then.response (C:\Users\<user name>\<project name>\WebStorm\protractorCucumberTest_v2\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:441:30)
           at <anonymous>
           at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
       From: Task: Protractor.get(https://angularjs.org/) - reset url
           at thenableWebDriverProxy.schedule (C:\Users\<user name>\<project name>\WebStorm\protractorCucumberTest_v2\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:807:17)
           at ProtractorBrowser.executeScriptWithDescription (C:\Users\<user name>\<project name>\WebStorm\protractorCucumberTest_v2\node_modules\protractor\built\browser.js:404
:28)
           at driver.controlFlow.execute.then.then.then (C:\Users\<user name>\<project name>\WebStorm\protractorCucumberTest_v2\node_modules\protractor\built\browser.js:679:25)
           at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (C:\Users\<user name>\<project name>\WebStorm\protractorCucumberTest_v2\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1376:14)
           at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\<user name>\<project name>\WebStorm\protractorCucumberTest_v2\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3084:14)
           at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\<user name>\<project name>\WebStorm\protractorCucumberTest_v2\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3067:27)
           at asyncRun (C:\Users\<user name>\<project name>\WebStorm\protractorCucumberTest_v2\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2927:27)
           at C:\Users\<user name>\<project name>\WebStorm\protractorCucumberTest_v2\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:668:7
           at <anonymous>
           at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
   - When I add "Be Awesome" in the task field # features\step_definitions\testone.steps.js:77
   - And I click the add button # features\step_definitions\testone.steps.js:81
   - Then I should see my new task in the list # features\step_definitions\testone.steps.js:86

1 scenario (1 failed)
4 steps (1 failed, 3 skipped)
0m00.250s
[15:58:29] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[15:58:29] I/launcher - internet explorerANY #01 failed 1 test(s)
[15:58:29] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[15:58:29] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
```

In the newly opened IE window there is a can't reach this page error message.

I've reviewed numerous Stack Overflow posts, and elsewhere, on ths topic. So far I can't get IE 11 to work. Thanks for any help...

NB:
Each time I run the test I see a different localhost port number appear in the newly opened IE window.

```
http://localhost:44234/
http://localhost:30821/
```

NB: I'm new to using JavaScript and Protractor, etc.

**Detailed Notes:**

All the required software has been installed locally to the project. I don't any versions of Protractor, etc. installed globally on the computer currently.

My WebStorm project structure is:

[image: WebStorm Project Structure]

My package.json file is:

```
{
  "name": "protractorCucumberTest_v2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "To test Protractor and Cucumber Integration",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "tbd"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "user name",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "chai-as-promised": "^7.1.1",
    "cucumber": "^4.0.0",
    "protractor": "^5.3.0",
    "protractor-cucumber-framework": "^4.2.0"
  }
}
```

My testone.feature file is:

```
#features/test.feature
Feature: Angular Task List
  As a basic user
  I should be able to add and remove tasks from the task list
  So that I can keep track of my tasks

  Scenario: Protractor and Cucumber Test
    Given I go to "https://angularjs.org/"
    When I add "Be Awesome" in the task field
    And I click the add button
    Then I should see my new task in the list
```

My testone.steps.js file is:

```
var {Given, Then, When} = require ('cucumber');
var chai = require('chai'),
    expect = chai.expect,
    chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);

Given(/^I go to "([^"]*)"$/, function (site) {
    return browser.get(site);
});

When(/^I add "([^"]*)" in the task field$/, function (task) {
    return element(by.model('todoList.todoText')).sendKeys(task);
});

When(/^I click the add button$/, function () {
    var el = element(by.css('[value="add"]'));
    return el.click();
});

Then(/^I should see my new task in the list$/, function () {
    var todoList = element.all(by.repeater('todo in todoList.todos'));
    expect(todoList.count()).to.eventually.equal(3);
    return expect(todoList.get(2).getText()).to.eventually.equal('Do not Be Awesome');
});
```

My cucumber.config.js file is:

```
exports.config = {

    capabilities: {
        seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
        // browserName: 'chrome'
        browserName: 'internet explorer',
        ignoreProtectedModeSettings: true,
        version: 'ANY'
    },

    localSeleniumStandaloneOpts : {
        jvmArgs : ["-Dwebdriver.ie.driver=./node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/IEDriverServer3.11.0.exe"],
    },

    framework: 'custom',
    frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
    specs: [
        './features/*.feature'
    ],
    cucumberOpts: {
        require: ['./features/step_definitions/*.steps.js'],
        tags: [],
        strict: true,
        dryRun: false,
        compiler: []
    },
    onPrepare: function () {
        browser.manage().window().maximize();
    }
};
```

The command I use to start the web server is:

```
node_modules\.bin\webdriver-manager start --ie
```

The command I use to start the test run is:

```
node_modules\.bin\protractor cucumber.config.js
```

**Software Version information:**

npm: v5.5.1

node: v8.9.1

protractor: v5.3.0

protractor-cucumber-framework: v4.2.0

cucumber-js: v4.0.0

JDK: 9.0.4

JRE: 9.0.4

```
node_modules\.bin\webdriver-manager status
[15:22:42] I/status - selenium standalone version available: 3.11.0 [last]
[15:22:42] I/status - chromedriver version available: 2.36 [last]
[15:22:42] I/status - geckodriver version available: v0.19.1 [last]
[15:22:42] I/status - IEDriverServer version available: 3.11.0 [last]
[15:22:42] I/status - android-sdk is not present
[15:22:42] I/status - appium is not present
```

**New Information as of 20 March 2018:**

I have tried the following technology stack on my system:

- Protractor
- Jasmine Test Framework
- IE 11
- Windows 10

Using this setup I can get the IE 11 test to execute. But when I use the following setup on the same computer with largely the same software the IE 11 test will **not** work. Switching the test framework to Cucumber from Jasmine seems to be the key. We want to use Cucumber for our BDD test automation programme.

- Protractor
- Cucumber Test Framework (via Cucumber and protractor-cucumber-framework)
- IE 11
- Windows 10

For the Protractor / Jasmine test setup that now works with IE 11 the following code files form the basis of my project:

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "protractorJasmineTest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Trial replication of locally installed variant the project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "tbd"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "user name",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "protractor": "^5.3.0"
  }
}
```

*protractor.config.js*

```
exports.config = {

    jvmArgs: ['-Dwebdriver.ie.driver=.\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\IEDriverServer3.11.1.exe'],
    framework: 'jasmine',
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    multiCapabilities: [
        {
            browserName: 'internet explorer',
            ignoreProtectedModeSettings: true,
            version: 'ANY'
            // ensureCleanSession : 'true'
            // browserName: 'chrome'
        }
    ],

    specs: ['spec.js']

}
```

*spec.js*

```
describe('Protractor Demo App', function() {

    it('should have a title', function() {
        browser.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30000);
        browser.driver.get('https://angularjs.org');
        expect(browser.driver.getTitle()).not.toEqual('Super Calculator');
    });

});
```

Comment: Often, setup webdriver enviroment for IE is more complex than for other browsers,  please read some tips from https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration

Comment: @yong : Thanks for that general info. I've looked through it and unfortunately I still don't have a working setup for my tests and IE11. I'm starting to think that this combination of technologies won't work with IE11.

Answer (score 0):

I've now heard back on the official #help-cucumber-js channel for the Cucumber OSS Community on Slack (cucumberbdd.slack.com) for this issue. Basically for now cucumber-js has issues with IE 11.

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/issues/1011.
[Loading dist/cucumber.js is broken in internet explorer 11 · Issue #1011 · cucumber/cucumber-js]

The following is a website link to test Cucumber running in your browser of choice that is part of the information in the above GitHub issue.

http://cucumber.github.io/cucumber-js/